# Phone reboots when connecting or removing charger

Tags: battery, charging

Since this morning my phone (LG E900) restarts about five seconds after connecting or unplugging the USB cable to charge. The sound effect that usually plays when starting to charge is also missing.

I dropped it a few days ago (probably for the third or fourth time) but I'd guess if it's related to the fall then it would started happening directly and not days after it. Otherwise I left a GPS tracking app open over night and the battery was depleted this morning but that too has happened before. Any idea what might be responsible?

<sub>*(I apologise for the poor tagging, but I'm not allowed to use new tags.)*</sub>

**EDIT:** Neither updating the phone software, nor rolling back the update, nor re-updating, nor resetting it to factory settings helped. I'll send it in for repairs now.

**EDIT 2:** They replaced a part of it and it worked again.

Comment: Could be a hardware issues. Can you turn the phone off and fully charge it without booting into Windows?

Comment: The phone apparently always boots while charging. Even if you forcibly turn it off.

Comment: I too have the same issue with an LG E900, it has also dramatically reduced battery life. However there are certain cables and chargers i can use which do not cause the restart and have the usual sound. The OEM charger and cable do cause the phone to restart. If you find a solution I would be interested.
David

Comment: I also have the same problem with LG E900 and started 2 days ago. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty certain this is a hardware issue. It could be related to the fall. It wouldn't be the first time I have seen issues with a device come up a few days after a drop, or water spillage, or something similar.

You can try doing a hard reset. I guess it is possible something got corrupt and now your phone is confused. Other than try try taking it back to where you got it and see if they can swap it out.

Comment: Is there a way of keeping the data with a replacement device?

Comment: Not built in, but see [these questions](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/search?q=backup) for ways to make it happen